# value of a variable not carried from one state to another in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Beginner question - any idea why the value from lemonSize in SELECT is not carrying over to SQUEEZE when switching lemonadeState? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

The app/code is part of intro to Kotlin course by Google which is for creating a lemonade app that rotates between screens https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-project-lemonade?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-four%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-project-lemonade#0

Here's where i think the problem is (I attached logs below that):

```
    // Default lemonSize to -1
    private var lemonSize = -1

    // Default the squeezeCount to -1
    private var squeezeCount = -1

    private var lemonTree = LemonTree()


when (lemonadeState) {
            SELECT -> {

                Log.d(TAG, "lemonadeState at beginning of SELECT *should be SELECT* lemonadeState = $lemonadeState")


                // Set the lemonSize (the number of squeezes needed) by calling the pick() method
                var lemonSize = LemonTree()//UPDATE
                Log.d(TAG, "randomly generated lemonSize using LemonTree -> lemonSize = $lemonSize")

                // Setting the squeezeCount (the number of times the user has squeezed the lemon) to 0.
                squeezeCount = 0
                Log.d(TAG, " setting squeezeCount to 0 -> squeezeCount = $squeezeCount")

                // Transition to the SQUEEZE state
                lemonadeState = SQUEEZE
                Log.d(TAG, "lemonadeState at bottom of SELECT *should be SQUEEZE* lemonadeState = $lemonadeState")
            }


            // TODO: When the image is clicked in the SQUEEZE state the squeezeCount needs to be
            //  INCREASED by 1 and lemonSize needs to be DECREASED by 1.
            //  - If the lemonSize has reached 0, it has been juiced and the state should become DRINK
            //  - Additionally, lemonSize is no longer relevant and should be set to -1
            SQUEEZE -> {


                Log.d(TAG, "at top of SQUEEZE *lemonSize should be 2-4* lemonSize = $lemonSize")
                Log.d(TAG, "at top of SQUEEZE *lemonadeState should be SQUEEZE* lemonadeState = $lemonadeState")

                //squeezeCount needs to be INCREASED by 1
                squeezeCount += 1

                //lemonSize needs to be DECREASED by 1.
                Log.d(TAG, "decreasing lemonSize by 1")
                Log.d(TAG, "lemonSize before decreasing by 1 lemonSize = $lemonSize")
                lemonSize = lemonSize - 1
                Log.d(TAG, "lemonSize after decreasing by 1 lemonSize = $lemonSize")

                //lemonSize = 0//REMOVE once done with testing
                //Log.d(TAG, "lemonSizeHere = $lemonSize ** REMOVE")

                //If the lemonSize has reached 0, it has been juiced and the state should become DRINK
                if (lemonSize == 0) {
                    lemonadeState = DRINK
                    //lemonSize = -1
                    Log.d(TAG, "lemonadeState when lemonSize == 0 lemonadeState = $lemonadeState")
                }
            }

/**
 * A Lemon tree class with a method to "pick" a lemon. The "size" of the lemon is randomized
 * and determines how many times a lemon needs to be squeezed before you get lemonade.
 */
class LemonTree {
    fun pick(): Int {
        return (2..4).random()
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
 2022-06-17 16:20:46.837 8549-8578/com.example.lemonade W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
    2022-06-17 16:20:49.788 8549-8549/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: lemonadeState at beginning of SELECT *should be SELECT* lemonadeState = select
    2022-06-17 16:20:49.789 8549-8549/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: randomly generated lemonSize using LemonTree -> lemonSize = com.example.lemonade.LemonTree@5c31497
    2022-06-17 16:20:49.790 8549-8549/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity:  setting squeezeCount to 0 -> squeezeCount = 0
    2022-06-17 16:20:49.793 8549-8549/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: lemonadeState at bottom of SELECT *should be SQUEEZE* lemonadeState = squeeze
    2022-06-17 16:21:04.177 8549-8549/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: at top of SQUEEZE *lemonSize should be 2-4* lemonSize = -1
    2022-06-17 16:21:04.179 8549-8549/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: at top of SQUEEZE *lemonadeState should be SQUEEZE* lemonadeState = squeeze
    2022-06-17 16:21:04.184 8549-8549/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: lemonSize before decreasing by 1 lemonSize = -1
    2022-06-17 16:21:04.186 8549-8549/com.example.lemonade D/MainActivity: lemonSize after decreasing by 1 lemonSize = -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're creating a top-level variable called `lemonSize` that's initialised to `-1`:

```
// Default lemonSize to -1
private var lemonSize = -1
```

That var is an `Int` which is inferred by the fact you assigned an integer value to it. This is meant to be size of your current lemon, right?

But inside your `SELECT` branch, you're doing this:

```
// Set the lemonSize (the number of squeezes needed) by calling the pick() method
var lemonSize = LemonTree()//UPDATE
```

There's two problems here - first, you're creating a *new variable* called `lemonSize` that only exists within the scope of those curly braces, the code that's executed when your state is `SELECT`. Whatever you do with that variable, it'll disappear once you exit that code block.

So when you reach the `SQUEEZE` branch, when that refers to `lemonSize` it's looking at the *top-level* one, which is still `-1`. The `lemonSize` variable you created in `SELECT` is gone, and wouldn't be visible to the `SQUEEZE` block anyway.

---

So what you should be doing in `SELECT` is *changing the value of that top-level 'lemonSize' variable* (which is what you're doing for `squeezeCount` and `lemonadeState` anyway):

```
// no 'var' this time, we're setting the top-level one
// THIS LINE WON'T WORK THOUGH! see below
lemonSize = LemonTree()
```

and here's where you run into your other problem - this won't work, because you're calling `LemonTree()` which is the constructor for the `LemonTree` class. You're creating a `LemonTree` object and assigning it to the `lemonSize` variable - which as we saw earlier, has been inferred to hold an `Int` type. And a `LemonTree` is not an `Int`! It can't go there

Your current code runs fine because you're basically creating a new local variable, that happens to be called `lemonSize`, and assigning a `LemonTree` to it - so you've created a variable with an inferred `LemonTree` type. And you don't do anything with it, so it's never a problem (although in your log you can see it prints out weird - `com.example.lemonade.LemonTree@5c31497` means it's a `LemonTree` object with a reference ID, ain't a number!)

---

So like the comment above that line says, you really need to be calling `pick()` to get your `lemonSize`. And you *could* create a new `LemonTree` object right there to pick from - but you already put one in a top-level variable, `lemonTree`. You probably just want to use that, right?

In the end, you probably want to do this:

```
SELECT -> {
    // pick a new current lemon and record its size
    lemonSize = lemonTree.pick()
    ...
}
```

and now your top-level `lemonSize` state variable has a new value everything can see.

Hope that makes sense! There's a few concepts to get familiar with here

Comment: That's exactly it! I didn't know how to get the pick function and every time I tried I got an error. when I looked at the exercise I did it seemed like we were instructed to call the but now from your explanation, I can see that it called the function within the class. thank you so much!!

Comment: @Moya.A no worries, hope it makes a bit more sense now!